# IIS 7 "bad request"

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc

Trying to access a url: server/Help/Upload/4 works fine, unfortunately we have to add a &iframe; on the end of this URL for it to be displayed in fancybox.

The URL with &iframe; on the end [server/Help/Upload/4/&iframe;] causes a IIS bad request.

I've googled for ages and can't seem to make any headway with this problem.. also tried the following:
 http://extended64.com/blogs/news/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-2-0-x64-you-may-get-http-400-bad-request-or-error-as-mentioned-in-kb-932552-or-826437.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this: http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/

Comment: And this is why link-only answers are bad.

Answer (score 1):

I also solved this using that same dirk.net sites directions, but there is one more step for x64 machines. You have to add a "DWORD" for "VerificationCompatibility" in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\" and set its value to "1".

Comment: since dirk.net links no longer work, i'm plugging this in here: The other registry root that needs this value is located here: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\"